# Intentando hacer login con laravel, da error Trying to get property <propiedad> of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\club\app\Http\Controllers\usuariosController.php on line 36

La función que tengo es la siguiente:

```php
public function login(Request $request){
    
        $response = ["status" =>0, "msg"=>""];

        $data =json_decode($request->getContent());
        $user = User::where('email', $data->email)->first();

        if($user){
            if(Hash::check($data->password, $user->password)){
                $token = $user->createToken("example"); //token universal

                $response["status"] = 1;
                $response["msg"] = $token -> plainTextToken;

                return redirect('privada');

            }else{
                $response["msg"] = "Credenciales incorrectas";
            }

        }else{
            $response["msg"] = "Usuario no encontrado";
        }

        return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: cual es la linea 36 en tu codigo, de casualidad es esta: `$user = User::where('email', $data->email)->first();`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ estas equivocado: json_decode, debuelve un array o un objeto, no un string... eso lo hace json_encode.

Comment: @Aitana  puedes hacer un `dd($data);` para ver que te muesta???

Answer (score 0):

```
// Esto sólo funciona si la ruta está en api.php y no en web.php
// $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

// Para obtener todos los datos del request se usa $request->all() y devuelve un arreglo (array)
$data = $request->all();
$user = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();
```